# Any way to have a UIToolbar always on the physical top of device regardless of orientation?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, orientation, constraints, uitoolbar

I'm trying to optimize the screen space for my graphics app and I want to support all orientations, but it would be great if I could leave the UIToolbar at the physical top of the iPhone or iPad (by the camera), and have the rest of the app and views properly deal with orientation. I will rotate the icons on the toolbar when I get a orientation event, but I want the toolbar and only the toolbar to stay put.

I want to use constraints, but can't figure out how to do this.

Anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constrains won't work to do this, because they would constrain the toolbar to the top of its superview, not the device, so if that superview rotates, so does your toolbar. I think you might have to do this by having a non-rotating view controller that contains your toolbar, and then just rotate a subview that contains your graphics.